# NotificationListener.requestInterruptionFilter sample

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been searching for a sample or tutorial to change the Interruptions in Lollipop. But I didn't find any complete one. I saw ideas or hints but not a complete one. With those ideas I have created a NotificationListener which is executed but I get this error:

**java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService$INotificationListenerWrapper cannot be cast to My.App.MyNotificationListenerService**

My Manifest:

```
    <service android:name=".MyNotificationListenerService"
          android:label="Some text here"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
          </intent-filter>
      </service>
```

My MyNotificationListenerService class:

```
public class MyNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService
{  
   @Override public void onCreate() 
   {  super.onCreate();       
   }


   @Override public void onDestroy() 
   {  super.onDestroy();      
   }


   @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
   {  return super.onBind(intent);
   }       

}
```

My activity:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyNotificationListenerService.class);
MyServiceConnection oMyServiceConnection = new MyServiceConnection();
bindService(serviceIntent, oMyServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
//Now we wait onconnect


class MyServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection 
{  @Override public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) 
   {  MyNotificationListenerService oMyNotificationListenerService= ((MyNotificationListenerService ) binder).getService(); <-- here is where I get the ClassCastException

      int iFilter = NotificationListenerService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY; //Or INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL or INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE
      oMyNotificationListenerService.requestInterruptionFilter(iFilter);              

   }

   @Override  public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
   {  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the [source of NotificationListenerService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.java#550), `NotificationListenerService` already implements `onBind()` and is how the `NotificationListenerService` communicates with the system.

By overriding `onBind()` to return your own interface, none of the methods that communicate with the system will work - you should see verbose level log messages along the lines of `"Unable to contact notification manager"`.

You can use other methods for communicating with your service such as [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I changed what you said but I get a ClassCastException error now in the commented line. Any hint with this? Please, see my edited question

Comment: Only the system can/should bind to a `NotificationListenerService` - you won't be able to use the `bindService()` method at all.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what you mean. Should I delete the "  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)" method?